# Queries work very slow with classic asp but fine with asp.net

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I have a strange situation. We have a legacy classic asp application that uses sql server 2008 R2 in the background and asp.net application that uses the same database as previous one.

All queries from classic asp are painfully slow while queries from asp.net are working just fine. Same database, same user, same type of queries but classic asp is just very, very slow.

Any ideas what could cause this? Our server is Win 2008 R2, SQL Server 2008 R2, IIS 7.5. IIS and SQL Server are on the same machine.

Comment: I would run a trace and compare the connection options such as the state of SET ARITHABORT et al, these can affect the selection of an execution plan from the cache & so affect performance for the same underlying query

Answer (score 1):

Try changing how you reference your instance. If you are referencing it as computer_name\instance or (local)\instance try updating server to 127.0.0.1.

You would also need to update your sql server networking settings in sql server configuration manager to enable sql server to work on this address.